# Trouble streaming from server "x" to wordpress site [icecast2]

Tags: wordpress, https, server, streaming, icecast

so as I said I'm having some trouble connecting "x" (server running icecast2) to my WordPress site.

things should be like this:

"x" with only public IP 1.2.3.4 let me listen to my radio from anywhere (tested)
WordPress site is up and that's fine

taking a look around I found that I may use `<audio>` to import the streaming coming from "1.2.3.4:xxxx/stream" but once the code is written in WordPress the audio player just won't do nothing

so here's my questions:
is it not meant to be done that way? Or am I just missing the "HTTPS" server-side?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If your website is using HTTPS - the stream should be using https protocol as well. Open browser console and see if there is "Insecure content" warning.